# Rails custom environment: keep certain subdirectories in app/models from loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, initialization, environment

I've created a custom environment in the Rails app I'm working on called `nhl_test`. The models for this environment are in `app/models/nhl` namespace. There are a number of other models in `app/models/[other_subdir]` that I don't want to autoload in this environment. So far I tried modifying the `config.paths` in my environment file similarly to how I modified the `db/migrate` location, like so:

## config/environments/nhl_test.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do

  config.eager_load = false

  config.paths["db/migrate"] = ["db/migrate/nhl"]
  config.paths["app/models"] = ["app/models/nhl"]
end
```

However, the other subdirectories of `app/models` are still being loaded. I can tell because there is code in those models that will break in this environment and I'm unable to run my tests using `RAILS_ENV=nhl_test m test/models/nhl` - they break with a stack trace that points to `app/models/mlb/base.rb`.

How can I keep any of the models except what's in `app/models/nhl` from being loaded in this environment??

**EDIT** It turns out it's this line in `test_helper.rb` that is causing the problem:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

Rather than loading all fixtures, I just need to load the fixtures in `test/fixtures/nhl` somehow...

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixture_path = Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'nhl')
  fixtures :all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by setting the `fixture_path` this way:

```
# test_helper.rb

ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', Rails.env.gsub('_test', ''))

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```